# on ng-click of md-option - Change ng-model of md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, md-select

I've md-select with multiple options enabled. 
By default ng-model of md-select does have one OBJECT value as array element.

on click/on selection of md-option - I want to update ng-model of md-select (Parent md-select)

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
<md-select ng-model="selected_item" ng-model-options="{trackBy: \'$value.id\'}" multiple>
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-click="onSelectItem(item)" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for happens automatically for you. When you set `md-select` as `multiple`, the ng-model will be an array of the selected items. See the "Option Groups" demo at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select for an example. You can select multiple toppings for your pizza and no extra code is needed to push those values into the model array.

Comment: adam0101 - Yeah That's right but before selected elements gets pushed to ng-model of md-select, I just want to apply custom logic on selected elements (array). How can I do that ?

Comment: What if you want one option selected atleast